Zyte Scrapy SSL issue
The below is my zyte api configuration and the error message. I am deploying my code windows 10 aws server which give ma this error message, when i run it on my pc it did not give me any error.
[zyte_api._retry] DEBUG: Retrying zyte_api._async.AsyncZyteAPI.get..request in       6.5062186265364215 seconds as it raised ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host api.zyte.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')].
"ZYTE_API_KEY = "MY_KEY"

    DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
        "http": "scrapy_zyte_api.ScrapyZyteAPIDownloadHandler",
        "https": "scrapy_zyte_api.ScrapyZyteAPIDownloadHandler",
    }
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        "scrapy_zyte_api.ScrapyZyteAPIDownloaderMiddleware": 1000,
    }
    REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_CLASS = "scrapy_zyte_api.ScrapyZyteAPIRequestFingerprinter"
    TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
    ZYTE_API_TRANSPARENT_MODE = True"


You need to install certificates on the second machine too.

How can I do this?

Same way as you did on the first machine, https://docs.zyte.com/misc/ca.html#ca

For the first machine I did not have done this, though I have tried it for the second but still it is giving me the same error.
